# Subtract two table columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two tables in a sheet, Table1 and Table2. I want to subtract the total of a column in Table2 from the total of a column in Table1. If what I want to do is adding them then this formula works fine:

```
=SUM(Table1[Amount],Table2[Cost])
```

How can I do the subtraction? I've tried:

```
=Table1[Amount] - Table2[Cost]
```

and it doesn't work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(Table1[Amount]) - SUM(Table2[Cost])
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you.

Comment: @AbdulRahman welcome to SuperUser by the way